# Is there any way to extract and get information from a Drools .drl file?

Tags: java, drools, rules

I am using Drools 7.5.0 version. I would want to know if there is any way to load a Drools ".drl" file and extract some information like the salience, the name of rule, metadata information, variables, antecedent, consequent, etc.

I want to save the rules data and process it to make statistics and other analysis.

Is the only solution to make a compiler?

Thank you.

Comment: No, not with the stable and public API. - USing the internal API might get you more, but you'll be on your own.

Comment: @laune Thank you. Do you know if there is any docs about that "internal API"?

Comment: You might ask this on the Drools user list. But I don't think so. Read the code.